# Select max date No result I want

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT
mat.matid,
MAX (to_date(to_char (matdatetable.matdateupdate,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')),
mat.matuserid,
mat.matname,    
mat.matprice    
FROM
matdatetable
LEFT JOIN mat ON matdatetable.sourceid = mat.matid
```

RESULT

```
matid   matdate update      matuserid    matname   matprice
-------------------------------------------------------------    
1       2012-01-01 0:0:0:0  0111-1       aaa       100
1       2012-08-01 0:0:0:0  0111-1       aaa       125
1       2013-08-30 0:0:0:0  0111-1       aaa       150
2       2012-01-01 0:0:0:0  0222-1       bbb       130
2       2012-08-21 0:0:0:0  0222-1       bbb       110
2       2013-07-30 0:0:0:0  0222-1       bbb       100
3       2012-01-01 0:0:0:0  0565-1       ccc       100
3       2013-09-30 0:0:0:0  0565-1       ccc       230
```

But I want to. Results

```
matid     matdate update    matuserid    matname   matprice
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2013-08-30 0:0:0:0  0111-1       aaa       150
2       2013-07-30 0:0:0:0  0222-1       bbb       100
3       2013-09-30 0:0:0:0  0565-1       ccc       230
```

Comment: Next time, please provide your table definition, Postgres version and a definition of what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       t.sourceid AS matid
      ,t.matdateupdate::date AS matdate_update
      ,m.matuserid
      ,m.matname   
      ,m.matprice
FROM   matdatetable t
LEFT   JOIN mat m ON m.matid = t.sourceid
ORDER  BY 1, t.matdateupdate DESC;
```

Gives you the *latest* (according to `matdateupdate`) entry per `sourceid`. Your question isn't clear what you want exactly.

Using `sourceid` rather than `matid`, since you have a `LEFT JOIN` and `matid` could be NULL. Or your use of `LEFT JOIN` is incorrect ...

Explanation for `DISTINCT ON` in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

`t.matdateupdate::date` casts your [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) (assuming for lack of information) to `date`. That seems to be what you want. If you really need the redundant time `00:00`, use [`datetrunc('day', t.matdateupdate)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) instead.